# Riemann Integral

Tags: integration, analysis

I tried to do the following excercise

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b$. We have a bounded function $ f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which has an integral or in other words, there exists a differentialable function $F : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $F'=f$.

Let $V={a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b}$ be a partition on $[a,b]$.

a) Show that for every $1 \leq j \leq n$ the following holds:
$$\inf_{I_j} f  (x_j -x_{xj-1}) \leq F(x_j) -F(x_{j-1}) \leq \sup_{I_j}f (x_j - x_{j-1}) $$

b) Show that $\underline{\int_a^b}f(x)dx\leq F(b) -F(a) \leq \overline{\int_a^b } f(x)dx$

c) Proof that if f is Riemann integrable then:

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = F(b) -F(a)$$

The problem where I get stuck with this question is that I don't know how I can use $F$. At first I started using the property I have to proof in question c. Perhaps I can use the meanvalue theorem, but I don't really understand how I can usethis properly without using information that I should proof. May I just state that $F'(c)=f(c)$ and if so how do I know it exists because to be integrable a function does not need to be continuous.

Comment: What do you know about $\dfrac{F(x_j) - F(x_{j-1})}{x_j - x_{j-1}}$?

Comment: There exists a $c\in ]x_{j-1} , x_j [$, such that $\frac{F(x_j) -F(x_{j-1})}{x_j -x_{j-1}} =  F'(c)$ But that would only be true if $F(x)$ is continuous? Or may I use this because the problem states that $F(x)$ is differentiable?

Comment: Every differentiable function is continuous, and $F$ is by assumption differentiable. The mean value theorem (for differentiable functions) thus asserts the existence of such a $c$. Do you see how that immediately gives you a)? And then b) and c)?

Comment: Yes I think how this directly gives a, because there exists a f(c) such that it holds and then $\inf f \leq f(c)$ gives the needed expression. Well c is easy if you use b). Because if if a function is Riemann integrable then the upper and lower integral are equal and then we can just use the squeeze theorem. Questin b I don't really see yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part a) follows from the mean value theorem. Since $F$ is by assumption everywhere differentiable, for every $1 \leqslant j \leqslant n$ there is a $c_j \in ]x_{j-1},x_j[$ such that

$$\frac{F(x_j) - F(x_{j-1})}{x_j - x_{j-1}} = F'(c_j) = f(c_j),$$

and by definition of $\inf$ and $\sup$ we have

$$\inf_{I_j} f \leqslant f(c_j) \leqslant \sup_{I_j} f.$$

Multiply that with $(x_j - x_{j-1})$ to obtain the inequality in a).

Adding these inequalities up, we obtain

$$\sum_{j = 1}^n (x_j -x_{j-1})\inf_{I_j} f \leqslant \sum_{j = 1}^n F(x_j) - F(x_{j-1}) = F(b) - F(a) \leqslant \sum_{j = 1}^n (x_j - x_{j-1})\sup_{I_j} f,$$

and the sums on the left resp. right are the lower resp. upper Darboux/Riemann sums for the partition $V$, so we have

$$L(V,f) \leqslant F(b) - F(a) \leqslant U(V,f).\tag{1}$$

But $(1)$ holds for *every* partition $V$ of the interval $[a,b]$, so

$$\underline{\int_a^b} f(x)\,dx = \sup_V L(V,f) \leqslant F(b) - F(a) \leqslant \inf_V U(V,f) = \overline{\int_a^b} f(x)\,dx.\tag{2}$$

Now c) is an immediate consequence of $(2)$, since Riemann integrability of $f$ over $[a,b]$ is equivalent to

$$\underline{\int_a^b} f(x)\,dx = \overline{\int_a^b} f(x)\,dx.$$